# How to impersonate the user in Anguilla,

Tags: cme

I want to impersonate the user with system administrator account in Anguilla. Can you please let me know how we can  achieve it.

I know this can be done via core service. But I need specific in Anguilla.

Comment: I don't think this is possible in Anguilla, as it doesn't handle authentication - all CM interactions are done in the CM core/back-end.

Comment: Thanks Nuno for the update. Is it possible to write a Web Service and then we can consume in Anguilla to impersonate the user ?

Answer (score 4):

You can do this in a server-side extension (e.g. Data extender). You can create your own (Session-aware) Core Service Client and use its `Impersonate` method before invoking whatever action you want to perform.

If you're using SDL Web 8, you can also use the `ElevatePrivileges` method to temporarily give the current user System Administrator privileges. This is easier (no need to configure a sysadmin account) and often more appropriate: the actions will be performed on behalf of the original user instead of an impersonated sysadmin account.