# How safe is using ElevatedPrivilegesScope to access a Component Tridion, if it is not accessible by the user

Tags: web8.5, event-system

I have a configuration Component in the Gloabal/Shared publication, We have Event System code which reads this Configuration Component using current component session, but in case if the current user does not have access to the Shared publication then Event System fails. i saw [this](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/20293/tridion-event-system-with-specific-user) post to ElevatePrivilages to sysadmin,and also gone through [this](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/16995/how-does-elevateprivileges-work) post and the code is below

```
using (ElevatedPrivilegesScope scope = new ElevatedPrivilegesScope(nonAdminSession, Privileges.SysAdmin))
{
    // Do your admin tasks
}
```

but i am afraid to use it as we have nlb in prod , if in any case any server gets down(in case of some outage or xyz reason) and at the same time when the event is triggered and somehow RestorePrivileges does not execute then the normal user will has all the privileges as admin an will start experiencing new cme with all the access of publications? please correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: Privilege Elevation is only applicable to the session you are creating, not for other sessions. The use case is really for when you need to do something programmatically that the user cannot do - but you still want to make sure it's traceable back to this user.

Comment: Thanks @NunoLinhares for your comments, we have image size checker event system code which basically restrict Content editors to add high size images, this image configuration component we are reading in Event system using current component session, but as i said this fails if the Content editor does not have access to the publication where the configuration component resides. If privileges does not revoke for some reasons then the same user will not see the all publication in the CME? (As he is in the same session and cme is accessible because one of the pro cme node is still up?)

Comment: Sorry, apparently it wasn't clear. You are not elevating the user's privilege, you are elevating the *Session* privilege. User is not in the same session, if he logs in via CME, the user is using a different session.

Comment: Thanks @NunoLinhares for your help,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are worried about -- the user somehow being left as an administrator - will not happen when you use ElevatedPrivilegesScope.

The elevation only applies to the scope, not to the user, so even if your code throws an exception afterwards there is no harm done. Heck, even if the user does actions *while your code is running*, they are not able to do anything other than what their normal permissions allow. Because again, it's not that the user's permissions are temporarily increased -- it's more that your code will do actions *on behalf of the user* without having to be constrained by their permissions.

Comment: Thanks @peter for this information , it clears my doubt :)