# Replacing "user: information in Publishing Queue while auto-publishing a page in workflow

Tags: workflow, sites-9

I have a few workflow-related questions and need some guidances.  We had a very simple workflow definition,

1. An editor creates and saves a page in the first activity
2. The content is automatically published in the second activity
   3..

When the page is automatically published,

1. The “User” of that entry in the “Publishing Queue” is displayed as “Tridion Content Manager System NT Authority User”, but we would like to show the editor’s name, is this possible?  If yes,

   a. Could I do it with “Impersonate”?

   b. Or set the values of “pageData.WorkflowInfo.Performer.Title”, “pageData.WorkflowInfo.Performer.Description” or “pageData.WorkflowInfo.Assignee.Title”, “pageData.WorkflowInfo.Assignee. Description” in the script, or something else before the actual publishing issued?

   c. Other thoughts?
2. Get the editor’s information

   a. From an Event System application, I found that I could get the revisor’s information of a page and am thinking to get the user information, "page.LoadedState.VersionInfo.Reviser.Title" and "page.LoadedState.VersionInfo.Reviser.Description", from there, but, I couldn’t find the same information in "pageData.VersionInfo.Revisor" from the script, even though I did find "pageData.DynamicVersionInfo.Revisor" but it does not contain any information, it’s null.  Am I looking at the wrong place?

   b. Could I find the previous activity information from the current activity (Auto publishing) then trace back to get the editor’s information?

   c. Is there a more straightforward way to get the information?

Thank you very much for your kind attention.

---

We are using Tridion Sites 9.0 and in the process to upgrade to 9.5.  Thanks.

Comment: Tang welcome to Tridion stack exchange . Please can you share your Tridion version that you are currently using

Comment: A more in-depth answer would be good, but I'm thinking the "elevate" options in the Content Manager APIs might help.

Comment: refer to this link https://gateway.sdl.com/apex/communityknowledge?articleName=000007559  and https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/20729/how-safe-is-using-elevatedprivilegesscope-to-access-a-component-tridion-if-it-i   ( for details related to elevate)

Comment: Tang any updates , did you try the elevate option is it working or you still having issue.